# Component angular2-data-table get error when run ng-serve

Tags: angular, datatable, datagrid, components, angular-cli

i'm trying use the component https://github.com/ggmod/angular-2-data-table, but when i declare DataTableModule in NgModule, the server gets me an error:

> ERROR in DataTableModule is not an NgModule

Somebody can help?

Comment: @did you solve it? have the same issue as well

Answer (score -1):

I don't get this 'not an NgModule' error here, just my TS compiler complaining.

Check your **ng-cli** version (in case you are using it), **typescript version**, **node version**.
I would also recommend you to try any other module similar to the one you are trying to use, just to make sure that the problem is with your project or local config.

If you haven't done this yet:

1. Try other data table modules for a2 like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable) (try it and let us know if it helps you get your work done)
2. Go to your first attempted [data-module github page](https://github.com/ggmod/angular-2-data-table) and open an issue to the main developer

Good luck :D